# Shutdown command not working within script

Tags: linux, centos

I have a script that's supposed to stop my minecraft server, and then restart the server. The problem is, whatever command I use to restart it doesn't work. I know the script is processing, because it saves my minecraft server then stops it.

Here's the relevant line in my crontab.

```
48 00 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/restart.sh
```

And here's my script

```
    screen -R minecraftserver -X "say Restarting server $(printf '\r'')"
    screen -R minecraftserver -X "stop $(printf '\r'')"
    shutdown -r now
```

The first two commands run perfectly, then my server stays up and doesn't reboot.

Also, I've tried switching it to `reboot -f` with no results.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add a full path of the command. Usually it's /sbin/shutdown. You also might need to add sudo.

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```